# Thesis 2 custom Page

Tags: plugins, pages

I have been installing lately the latest version from Thesis and getting to the point to make a custom landing Page. I have been building a plugin and I would like to link the content of it to my newly created landing Page. How do I do this, where can I upload my custom php code for the thesis landing Page?

thanks in advanced

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. As Thesis is a commercial Theme, we have no way of seeing the code to be able to help answer your question. I would recommend trying Thesis support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook from the custom.php file inside /wp-content/thesis/skin/skin-name/

Or you can use this box http://www.rickbeckman.org/the-brazenly-coded-box-for-thesis-2-0/ to write PHP codes directly inside Thesis skin editor.